# Does Hbase have region replications

Tags: hbase

I knew Hbase has replicates of WAL and Hfile, but all of these are stored in HDFS as persistence. So will Hbase also provides region level replicas. We know Region contains BlockCache and MemCache, if only one Region instance handle requests, how does Hbase solve the hot point requests.

Additionally, if only one region instance, Hbase would be always consistency, right please? Because all readers just read from the one region, they always see the same data? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Latest versions of HBase has a feature called “region replication”. 
 For each region of a table, there can be multiple replicas that are opened in different Region Servers. By default, the region replication is set to 1, so only a single region replica is deployed and there are no changes from the original model. If region replication is set to 2 or more, then the master assigns replicas of the regions of the table. The Load Balancer ensures that the region replicas are not co-hosted in the same Region Servers and also in the same rack (if possible).

To enable, Set `hbase.region.replica.replication.enabled to true` in hbase-site.xml.

Creating tables with High Availability of regions:

```
CREATE 't1', 'f1', {REGION_REPLICATION => 2}
```

HBase provides consistency model for get or scan operations.

```
public enum Consistency {
   STRONG,
   TIMELINE
 }
```

Consistency.STRONG is the default consistency model provided by HBase. If a table has region replication = 1, or has region replicas but the reads are done with time consistency enabled, the read is always performed by the primary regions

Querying secondary regions:

```
Get get = new Get(row); 
get.setConsistency(CONSISTENCY.TIMELINE);
...
Result result = table.get(get);
```

For scan

```
scan 't1', {CONSISTENCY => 'TIMELINE'}
```

For more details, you can refer to [this](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.0/bk_hadoop-ha/content/ch_HA-HBase.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer, one more question please, if we set Region replication is 3, will that impact Hbase consistency? I guess in that case if we set write_level=1, it won't be a consistency system unless we set write_level=3. Right please? Thanks!

Comment: Secondary region replications are read only. Writes, always go to primary region. Periodically, based on the configuration, HBase replicates secondary regions. Some times, data in secondary regions may be stale. If we want latest data, we need to specify  consistency level as STRONG.

Comment: Thanks a lot, in load balance perspective, if Hbase doesn't have Region Replication, do you think it's load balance performance is better than MongoDB or Cassandra please, or worse than them, Appreciate!